# Proof that two lines intersect each other at precisely one point in Idris

Tags: idris

I recently attempted to prove that given two lines, they intersect at one and only one point in Idris. Here is what I came up with:

```hs
interface (Eq line, Eq point) => Plane line point where 
  -- Abstract notion for saying three points lie on the same line.
  colinear : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  coplanar : point -> point -> point -> Bool
  contains : line -> point -> Bool

  -- Intersection between two lines
  intersects_at : line -> line -> point -> Bool

  -- If two lines l and m contain a point a, they intersect at that point.
  intersection_criterion : (l : line) -> 
                           (m : line) ->
                           (a : point) ->
                           (contains l a = True) -> 
                           (contains m a = True) -> 
                           (intersects_at l m a = True)

  -- If l and m intersect at a point a, then they both contain a.
  intersection_result : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        (intersects_at l m a = True) ->
                        (contains l a = True, contains m a = True)

  -- For any two distinct points there is a line that contains them.
  line_contains_two_points : (a :point) -> 
                             (b : point) ->
                             (a /= b) = True ->
                             (l : line ** (contains l a = True, contains l b = True ))

  -- If two points are contained by l and m then l = m
  two_pts_define_line : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        (b : point) ->
                        ((a /= b) = True) ->
                        contains l a = True ->
                        contains l b = True ->
                        contains m a = True -> 
                        contains m b = True -> 
                        ((l == m) = True)

  same_line_same_pts : (l : line) ->
                       (m : line) ->
                       (a : point) ->
                       (b : point) ->
                       ((l /= m) = True) ->
                       contains l a = True ->
                       contains l b = True ->
                       contains m a = True ->
                       contains m b = True ->
                       ((a == b) = True)

  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** 
                           (colinear a b c = False, 
                           (a /= b) = True, 
                           (b /= c) = True, 
                           (a /= c) = True))

  -- Any line contains at least two points.
  contain_two_pts : (l : line) ->
                    (a : point ** b : point ** 
                    (contains l a = True, contains l b = True))

-- If two lines intersect at a point and they are not identical, that is the o-
-- nly point they intersect at.
intersect_at_most_one_point : Plane line point =>
  (l : line) -> (m : line) -> (a : point) -> (b : point) ->
  ((l /= m) = True) ->
  (intersects_at l m a = True) ->
  (intersects_at l m b = True) ->
  ((a == b) = True)

intersect_at_most_one_point l m a b l_not_m int_at_a int_at_b =
  same_line_same_pts
  l
  m
  a
  b
  l_not_m
  (fst (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (fst (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
  (snd (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (snd (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
```

My main concerns is that I have an "inefficient" (possibly incorrect?) formulation of the axioms. The code runs and compiles, but it feels like for instance, somehow, `intersection_criterion` and `intersection_result` could be somehow made into one axiom. Nevertheless, any advice is appreciated.

(This is also on Github [here](https://github.com/thyrgle/scratch) in the file `hilbert.idr`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It still may be far from perfect, but I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50961282/667648) on Stackoverflow related to this, and received [an excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964268/667648) from xash.

I have attempted to cure my [Boolean blindness](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/15/boolean-blindness/). If I understand correctly, the operator `==` asks the question "Is the left hand side equal to the right hand side?" Instead, I want to say: "I have a proof that this holds."

To fix this, I changed a lot of my functions like `colinear` to more closely match the `(=)` signature:

```
colinear : point -> point -> point -> Bool
```

becomes:

```
Colinear : point -> point -> point -> Type
```

Also, I removed `a /= b` and instead replaced it with `Not (a = b)`.

Here was the resulting code:

```
interface Plane line point where 
  -- Abstract notion for saying three points lie on the same line.
  Colinear : point -> point -> point -> Type
  Coplanar : point -> point -> point -> Type
  Contains : line -> point -> Type

  -- Intersection between two lines
  IntersectsAt : line -> line -> point -> Type

  -- If two lines l and m contain a point a, they intersect at that point.
  intersection_criterion : (l : line) -> 
                           (m : line) ->
                           (a : point) ->
                           Contains l a -> 
                           Contains m a -> 
                           IntersectsAt l m a

  -- If l and m intersect at a point a, then they both contain a.
  intersection_result : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        IntersectsAt l m a ->
                        (Contains l a, Contains m a)

  -- For any two distinct points there is a line that contains them.
  line_contains_two_points : (a : point) -> 
                             (b : point) ->
                             Not (a = b) ->
                             (l : line ** (Contains l a, Contains l b))

  -- If two points are contained by l and m then l = m
  two_pts_define_line : (l : line) ->
                        (m : line) ->
                        (a : point) ->
                        (b : point) ->
                        Not (a = b) ->
                        Contains l a ->
                        Contains l b ->
                        Contains m a -> 
                        Contains m b -> 
                        (l = m)

  same_line_same_pts : (l : line) ->
                       (m : line) ->
                       (a : point) ->
                       (b : point) ->
                       Not (l = m) ->
                       Contains l a ->
                       Contains l b ->
                       Contains m a ->
                       Contains m b ->
                       (a = b)

  -- There exists 3 non-colinear points.
  three_non_colinear_pts : (a : point ** b : point ** c : point ** 
                           (colinear a b c = False, 
                           Not (a = b), 
                           Not (b = c), 
                           Not (a = c)))

  -- Any line contains at least two points.
  contain_two_pts : (l : line) ->
                    (a : point ** b : point ** 
                    (Contains l a, Contains l b))

-- If two lines intersect at a point and they are not identical, that is the o-
-- nly point they intersect at.
intersect_at_most_one_point : Plane line point =>
  (l : line) -> (m : line) -> (a : point) -> (b : point) ->
  Not (l = m) ->
  IntersectsAt l m a ->
  IntersectsAt l m b ->
  (a = b)

intersect_at_most_one_point l m a b l_not_m int_at_a int_at_b =
  same_line_same_pts
  l
  m
  a
  b
  l_not_m
  (fst (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (fst (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
  (snd (intersection_result l m a int_at_a))
  (snd (intersection_result l m b int_at_b))
```